# DocuSign API "GET envelope" route not taking into account "include" parameter

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to use this route https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get to get information on a specific Envelope in DocuSign, and I wanted to add the `?include=recipients` parameter so as to get individual signers status too, but the parameter does not seem to do anything

Trying other values to include (documents, tags, etc). Doesn't change the response either.

Same result whether I try from my own code or from DS' "API explorer" tool

Am I using it wrong or is it a bug in the API?

Comment: can you double check you're using 2.1 and 2.0? what's the URL of your API call?

Comment: You are absolutely right, was using 2.0 but this parameter is only available with 2.1!

Comment: ok, happy to help. I added a formal answer. Please mark this as answered if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parameter `(?include=recipients)` is a new addition in the v2.1 API. You should ensure that the API endpoint you are calling has the v2.1 in the URL and not v2. You cannot use this feature with the v2.0 API. There are other reasons to use latest API 2.1 and it's supported by all SDKs.